# Matching an address to a stack during Windbg Kernel Debugging

Tags: kernel, windbg, callstack

I've got an address I found while debugging, and I suspect it belongs to the call stack of some thread of some process.

What's the best way to found out which thread it is (or that's my hypothesis is false)?

P.S. I could have used `!process` and then `.process` and `!thread` repeatedly, but there must be a better way.

P.S.S. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the situation while user-mode debugging.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by '[address] belongs to the call stack'? Maybe you meant to say that the address is in segment that is allocated for stack?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have symbols loaded you may be able to glean some information from the address using [`ln <address>`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2008/06/11/special-command-listing-the-nearest-symbols-with-ln.aspx). From there, it shouldn't be hard to make a guess at which process/thread is involved.

If that doesn't do what you'd like, you can move on to the bruteforce approach. Your best bet for searching is to automate fetching of the callstacks in a more searchable format. The following will write them all out to a file that you can search through more easily with your favourite text editor.

```
.logopen c:\stacks.txt; !for_each_process "!process @#Process; ~*kv1000"; .logclose
```

This will take a while so go get some coffee. If you are feeling lucky, you can search the output directly from windbg as so:

```
.shell -ci "!for_each_process \"!process @#Process; ~*kv1000\"" findstr "deadbeef"
```

(replacing *deadbeef* with the address you are looking for)

Hopefully this does what you'd like or at least points you toward scripting out a solution.